# Is there a stored procedure that creates the sysdiagrams table and supporting stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

Currently, our local builds include a database build & deploy step that deploys databases to the developers' local machines based on a database model contained within a Sql Server 2008 Database Project. This is fine for deploying the database schema, but is unable to deploy any database diagrams that have been defined.

In order to deploy the diagrams, we are currently having to include CREATE scripts for the sysdiagrams table and the stored procedures upon which the designer is dependent, and a data insert script for the diagram definitions, as part of the post deployment stage.

Is there a better way to deploy the sysdiagrams table and stored procedures? These are created within sql server management studio when clicking yes in the dialog that asks whether I'd like to create the support objects for diagramming - does this invoke something that I can hook into? I can't find a relevant stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a means of doing this and you should bear in mind that Database diagram format differs between releases of SQL Server thus a SQL2008 diagram can't be directlt inserted into a SQL 2000 database. The diagram is storede as a binary file within the database.

You could carry on doing what you're currently doing or have a lokk at the tool on [this link](http://www.conceptdevelopment.net/Database/ScriptDiagram2008/).

NOTE: I have no connection to the site and so can't vouch for it, but it may give you some ideas.

Comment: Can vouch. Great tool. Link is broken so copy source in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22316032/224976)

Comment: ConceptDevelopment code updated here for SQL2012: https://github.com/neutmute/ScriptDiagram

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool I've used to import and export SQL diagrams. The version for 2008 is Tool_ScriptDiagram2008 by Craig Dunn. Take a look at http://www.conceptdevelopment.net/Database/ScriptDiagram2008/. I use it to export the diagrams to a text format that can be saved in source control, then these scripts from souce control can be used to recreate the diagrams on any machine.

Comment: Since the link is down, I posted my source in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22316032/224976)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a procedure. If you want to keep your diagrams in safe place - script the table sysdiagrams and supporting objects if any with data and keep the generated script. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

My minor modifications to a well used stored procedure that can create the sysdiagrams table ([original source](http://www.conceptdevelopment.net/Database/ScriptDiagram2008)):

```
/**

<summary>

    Script Sql Server 2008 diagrams (inspired by usp_ScriptDatabaseDiagrams for Sql Server 2000 by Clay Beatty,
    and Tool_ScriptDiagram2005 by yours truly)

</summary>

<example>

    USE [YourDatabaseName]
    EXEC ScriptDiagram2008 'DiagramName'

</example>

<author>Craig Dunn</author>

<remarks>

    Helpful Articles
    ----------------

    1) Upload / Download to Sql 2005
        http://staceyw.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!F4A38E96E598161E!404.entry

    2) MSDN: Using Large-Value Data Types
        http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178158.aspx

    3) "original" Script, Save, Export SQL 2000 Database Diagrams
        http://www.thescripts.com/forum/thread81534.html

    <![CDATA[ http://groups-beta.google.com/group/comp.databases.ms-sqlserver/browse_frm/thread/ca9a9229d06a56f9?dq=&hl=en&lr=&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&prev=/groups%3Fdq%3D%26num%3D25%26hl%3Den%26lr%3D%26ie%3DUTF-8%26oe%3DUTF-8%26group%3Dcomp.databases.ms-sqlserver%26start%3D25 ]]>

    4) SQL2008 'undocumented' sys.fn_varbintohexstr
        http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic664234-1496-1.aspx

</remarks>

<param name="name">Name of the diagram in the Sql Server database instance</param>

*/

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ScriptDiagram2008]
(
    @DiagramName VARCHAR(128)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @diagram_id INT
    DECLARE @index      INT
    DECLARE @size       INT
    DECLARE @chunk      INT
    DECLARE @line       VARCHAR(max)

    -- Set start index, and chunk 'constant' value
    SET @index = 1  -- 
    SET @chunk = 32    -- values that work: 2, 6
                    -- values that fail: 15,16, 64

    -- Get PK diagram_id using the diagram's name (which is what the user is familiar with)
    SELECT 
        @diagram_id = diagram_id,
        @size = DATALENGTH(definition) 
    FROM sysdiagrams 
    WHERE [name] = @DiagramName

    IF @diagram_id IS NULL
    BEGIN
        PRINT '/**<error>'
        PRINT 'Diagram name [' + @DiagramName + '] could not be found.'
        PRINT '</error>*/' 
    END
    ELSE -- Diagram exists
    BEGIN
        -- Now with the diagram_id, do all the work
        PRINT '/**'
        PRINT '<summary>'
        PRINT 'Restore diagram ''' + @DiagramName + ''''
        PRINT '</summary>'
        PRINT '<remarks>'
        PRINT 'Generated by ScriptDiagram2008'
        PRINT 'Will attempt to create [sysdiagrams] table if it doesn''t already exist'
        PRINT '</remarks>'
        PRINT '<generated>' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 121), 16) + '</generated>'
        PRINT '*/'
        PRINT 'PRINT ''=== ScriptDiagram2008 restore diagram [' + @DiagramName + '] ==='''
        PRINT '    -- If the sysdiagrams table has not been created in this database, create it!
                IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''sysdiagrams'')
                BEGIN
                    -- Create table script generated by Sql Server Management Studio
                    -- _Assume_ this is roughly equivalent to what Sql Server/Management Studio
                    -- creates the first time you add a diagram to a 2008 database
                    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sysdiagrams](
                        [name] [sysname] NOT NULL,
                        [principal_id] [int] NOT NULL,
                        [diagram_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                        [version] [int] NULL,
                        [definition] [varbinary](max) NULL,
                    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
                    (
                        [diagram_id] ASC
                    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ,

                     CONSTRAINT [UK_principal_name] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
                    (
                        [principal_id] ASC,
                        [name] ASC
                    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) 
                    ) 

                    EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N''microsoft_database_tools_support'', @value=1 , @level0type=N''SCHEMA'',@level0name=N''dbo'', @level1type=N''TABLE'',@level1name=N''sysdiagrams''
                    PRINT ''[sysdiagrams] table was created as it did not already exist''
                END

                -- Target table will now exist, if it didn''t before'

        PRINT 'SET NOCOUNT ON -- Hide (1 row affected) messages'
        PRINT 'DECLARE @newid INT'
        PRINT ''
        PRINT 'PRINT ''Create row for new diagram'''

        -- Output the INSERT that _creates_ the diagram record, with a non-NULL [definition],
        -- important because .WRITE *cannot* be called against a NULL value (in the WHILE loop)
        -- so we insert 0x so that .WRITE has 'something' to append to...

        PRINT 'BEGIN TRY'
        PRINT '    PRINT ''Write diagram ' + @DiagramName + ' into new row (and get [diagram_id])'''
        SELECT @line =  
              '    INSERT INTO sysdiagrams ([name], [principal_id], [version], [definition])'
            + ' VALUES (''' + [name] + ''', '+ CAST (principal_id AS VARCHAR(100))+', '+CAST (version AS VARCHAR(100))+', 0x)'

        FROM sysdiagrams WHERE diagram_id = @diagram_id

        PRINT @line
        PRINT '    SET @newid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()'
        PRINT 'END TRY'
        PRINT 'BEGIN CATCH'
        PRINT '    PRINT ''XxXxX '' + Error_Message() + '' XxXxX'''
        PRINT '    PRINT ''XxXxX END ScriptDiagram2008 - fix the error before running again XxXxX'''
        PRINT '    RETURN'
        PRINT 'END CATCH'
        PRINT ''
        PRINT 'PRINT ''Now add all the binary data...'''
        PRINT 'BEGIN TRY'

        WHILE @index < @size
        BEGIN
            -- Output as many UPDATE statements as required to append all the diagram binary
            -- data, represented as hexadecimal strings

            SELECT @line =  
                 '    UPDATE sysdiagrams SET [definition] .Write ('
                + ' ' + UPPER(sys.fn_varbintohexstr (SUBSTRING (definition, @index, @chunk)))
                + ', null, 0) WHERE diagram_id = @newid -- index:' + CAST(@index AS VARCHAR(100))

            FROM    sysdiagrams 
            WHERE    diagram_id = @diagram_id

            PRINT @line
            SET @index = @index + @chunk
        END

        PRINT ''
        PRINT '    PRINT ''=== Finished writing diagram id '' + CAST(@newid AS VARCHAR(100)) + ''  ==='''
        PRINT '    PRINT ''=== Refresh your Databases-[DbName]-Database Diagrams to see the new diagram ==='''
        PRINT 'END TRY'
        PRINT 'BEGIN CATCH'
        PRINT '    -- If we got here, the [definition] updates didn''t complete, so delete the diagram row'
        PRINT '    -- (and hope it doesn''t fail!)'
        PRINT '    DELETE FROM sysdiagrams WHERE diagram_id = @newid'
        PRINT '    PRINT ''XxXxX '' + Error_Message() + '' XxXxX'''
        PRINT '    PRINT ''XxXxX END ScriptDiagram2008 - fix the error before running again XxXxX'''
        PRINT '    RETURN'
        PRINT 'END CATCH'
    END
END
```

Usage for the the dbo.[ScriptDiagram2008](http://www.conceptdevelopment.net/Database/ScriptDiagram2008)(@DiagramName) stored procedure:

```
exec dbo.ScriptDiagram2008('My diagram')
```

It will generate a SQL script that you can save as a "portable" version of your diagram. Executing the script inserts the diagram named "My diagram" into the sysdiagrams table. It even creates that sysdiagrams table if it does not already exist.